# Waterproofing shower

Tags: shower, tile, waterproofing

When applying a rubber waterproofing like red gaurd or aquadefence. What kisnd of morter do you use modified or unmodified. I have read through each one amd it dosnet say anything about what morter to use when your ready to tile.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what mortar to use *before* applying waterproofer (e.g. Redgard), then use unmodified with an alkali-resistant cement board tape.

If you mean what kind of mortar to use *after* the application of waterproofer (i.e. to apply the tiles), then use whatever mortar is correct for the tile of your choice.

For instance, larger or natural tiles usually need a modified mortar, while smaller tiles can use unmodified just fine. The packages of mortar will describe their appropriate tile use.

Answer (score 0):

I have used unmodified on a cement board just one time to show me that I needed to use modified after it set so fast that it turned to sand after it dried. Do not use unmodified over the joints before you apply the waterproofing.